# Is there a way in Shell to substitute a value into the regex pattern?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I was writing a Python script to convert a certain format of XML file to JSON format. The exercise is from the missing semester at MIT.
([xml_to_json](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/editors/))

I have an issue with how to substitute a value in a regex pattern in the shell. (I am using a subprocess library in python to access the shell sed program)

I used Python library 'subprocess' and did just as follows.

```
# xml_to_json.py

num = 1001(or it could be other numbers)

subprocess.call(["sed","-E","-i","","${num}s/,$//","example-data.xml"])
```

What I am trying to do is using the variable 'num', replace the value to this position(${num}) so that I could substitute to the certain line number.

I know that you can use the variable in the shell like this($variable) but it doesn't seem to be working here.

I know that I can define a range of line number where I want to do the 'sed' works such as "%1,100s/regexpattern/regex/".

How can I put the line number in front of 's' using a variable?

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you apply. Asking for "shell" code in particular is meaningless. Additionally, `sed` is not a "shell program". It is a program, yes, but it is not in any way dependent on any shell.

Comment: Your Python code doesn't run any shell at all; it's starting the sed executable directly without anything in the way. The best thing is to embrace that and use Python to do the substitution.

Comment: (also, converting between XML and JSON should be done using tools that actually know the escaping rules for both languages; sed is completely unsuited for any role in the process)

Answer (score 3):

`num` is not a shell variable, but a python variable. Simply build your parameter string in python to contain the correct value:

```py
subprocess.call(["sed","-E","-i","", str(num) + "s/,$//","example-data.xml"])
```

or with f-strings:

```py
subprocess.call(["sed","-E","-i","", f'{num}s/,$//',"example-data.xml"])
```

Be aware that carelessly interpolating values into shell commands could leave you open to command injection. In this case it seems to be safe because `num` is a simple numeric value and not user-provided data.

Comment: I believe in the first snippet you need to write `str(num)` instead of `num`

Comment: @Alex thanks, you are right. Too much JavaScript lately :)

Comment: Also there's no shell to inject anything into here. Granted, some versions of sed (like the GNU one) have features that allow arbitrary command execution, but systems with better designed tools don't have that fault.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, it might not be possible with this specific parameter. But if for instance the string "sed" was user-provided, we could have big problems. The important word in my last paragraph is "carelessly" :)